# How to suppress excel large info on clipboard message

Tags: vba, excel

I am copying data from worksheet ws and am trying to paste just the values back to the original sheet, thus overwriting the original data with plain text.  When I close the workbook I get an excel message telling me "There is a large amount of information on the clipboard.  Do you want to be able to past this information into another program?"  I will never want to do this.  I don't want this message to not appear or assume the answer is "No".

```
Function FindPresenters(MyDate As Date, MyWS As String) As String
    'MyDate is in format of 10/3/2016
    'MyWS is the target worksheet to find MyDate
    Dim GCell As Range
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim MyLoop As Integer
    Dim Found As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application") 'New Excel.Application
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    xlApp.Visible = True

    Set WB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open ("Sched(Others).xlsx")
    Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Oct 2016 Training Schedule")
    With WS '.UsedRange
        '.Cells.Select
        .UsedRange.Select
        .Cells.Copy
        .Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
         Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'This should suppress msg, but doesn't
        .Range("B2").Select
    End With
    WS.Activate
    Set GCell = WS.Cells.Find(MyDate)

    Found = False
    For MyLoop = 1 To MaxDayItems 'Find the entrees for the month
        Debug.Print GCell.Offset(MyLoop, 0).Text
        If Not Found And InStr(1, GCell.Offset(MyLoop, 0).Text, "C.O.") > 0 Then         
           'Found data
            Found = True
            FindPresenters = GCell.Offset(MyLoop, 0).Text
            MyLoop = MaxDayItems + 1 'Terminate searching
        End If
    Next MyLoop

Done:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Tried this to suppress the message
    WB.Close True  'This is where the Clipboard error appears
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set WS = Nothing
    Set WB = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
Exit Function

'Error Handling section.
ErrorHandler:
    ...
    GoTo Done

End Function
```

Comment: Don't use the clipboard? You're only pasting values - just write them directly.

Comment: I am not using the clipboard other than copy paste.  What do you mean "write them directly"?  This file is provided and I just need to modify it to be text. -Thx

Comment: See the answer below: `WS.UsedRange.Value = WS.UsedRange.Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the cells you are copying belong to `xlApp` (a separate instance of Excel.Application) you will need to make `xlApp.CutCopyMode` equal false.

```
xlApp.CutCopyMode = False
```

I agree with Comintern's comment "You're only pasting values - just write them directly"

It appears that you are simple replacing all the formulas on the worksheet with their values.  This can be achieved by simply like this:

```
WS.UsedRange.Value = WS.UsedRange.Value
```

Comment: The xlapp.CutCopyMode statement sounds promising.  I will try that.  I think the 'WS.UsedRange.Value = WS.UsedRange.Value' statement is only grabbing the cells which have data, but does this execute the equivalent of a copy paste?  What does that statement do? - Thx

Comment: It will replace all the formulas on the worksheet with their values

Comment: The xlapp.CutCopyMode resolved the original problem, but it sounds like using WS.UsedRange.Value = WS.UsedRange.Value would be a better solution.  I will mark this as the solution to the original problem, but would like it if you would explain WS.UsedRange.Value = WS.UsedRange.Value.  I sounds to me like this would not use the clipboard and would be faster, but I don't know how to use this.  Thanks much for your help!